# Scala searches for an obscure Main class

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

I have what should be a simple scala script that looks as follows:

```
object SaveTaggedSenseTask {                                                    
  def main(args:  Array[String]) {
    val reader:SenseEvalAllWordsDocumentReader = new SenseEvalAllWordsDocumentReader()
    reader.parse(args(0))                                                   
    println(reader.sentences)                                               
    reader.sentences()
  }
}
```

The `SenseEvalAllWordsDocumentReader` is a java defined class that is just a wrapper for a SAX parser.  Calling sentences should simply return a java List of of another java defined class called Sentence.  If i run this code using

```
scala -cp jar-with-everything.jar SaveTaggedSenseTask.scala path/to/file.xml
```

I get the following horrible mess of an output:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main (args = /home/stevens35/senseEval/senseEval3-allwords/english-all-words.xml, classpath = /tmp/scalascript7300484879512233483.tmp:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/home/stevens35/devel/src/scala-2.9.1.final/lib/jline.jar:/home/stevens35/devel/src/scala-2.9.1.final/lib/scala-compiler.jar:/home/stevens35/devel/src/scala-2.9.1.final/lib/scala-dbc.jar:/home/stevens35/devel/src/scala-2.9.1.final/lib/scala-library.jar:/home/stevens35/devel/src/scala-2.9.1.final/lib/scalap.jar:/home/stevens35/devel/src/scala-2.9.1.final/lib/scala-swing.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/home/stevens35/devel/C-Cat/wordnet/.:/home/stevens35/devel/C-Cat/wordnet/target/extendOntology-wordnet-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar:/home/stevens35/devel/C-Cat/wordnet/../data/target/extendOntology-data-1.0.jar)                                               
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:103)                                                                 
        at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:33)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:40)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.scala$tools$nsc$ScriptRunner$$runCompiled(ScriptRunner.scala:171)                                                       
        at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$runScript$1.apply(ScriptRunner.scala:188)                                                                      
        at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$runScript$1.apply(ScriptRunner.scala:188)                                                                      
        at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$withCompiledScript$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ScriptRunner.scala:157)                                                      
        at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$withCompiledScript$1.apply(ScriptRunner.scala:131)                                                             
        at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner$$anonfun$withCompiledScript$1.apply(ScriptRunner.scala:131)                                                             
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.package$.waitingForThreads(package.scala:26)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.withCompiledScript(ScriptRunner.scala:130)                                                                              
        at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.runScript(ScriptRunner.scala:188)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ScriptRunner.runScriptAndCatch(ScriptRunner.scala:201)                                                                               
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:58)                                                                            
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:80)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:89)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

I'm assuming that this means scala is looking for some class named Main and can't find it, but I can't figure out why it would even think of looking for this.  Furthermore, if i delete the `reader.sentences()` line, or do something like call `size()` on it, the problem goes away.  I can only guess that scala is somehow inferring that a class named Main should exist due to this call, but I don't see any obvious workaround.

Thoughts?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for adding the boxes Rahul, I hadn't known I could do that!

Answer (score 5):

You are conflating Scala script and scala program. When using `object` and `def main`, you should compile the program with `scalac`, and then call it with `scala` passing the name of the `object` that contains the `main` method.

When calling as a script, you should remove `object` and `def main`, and just put your program. The arguments will still be in `args`.

Now, one of the features of Scala 2.9.1 is that one could mix script and program invocation, but it is obviously not working here for some reason. I suggest you pick one way of doing things, and stick to that.

Comment: Ah, interesting.  I'm still fairly new to scala and wasn't actually sure how to write in a more script-like fasion.

Comment: Also, I tried running as a pure script as you suggested and the exception still gets thrown. But, when I tried compiling it with scalac, i get an even more horrible looking exception that boils down to some java classes that Sentence is using.  I have a feeling this is entirely dependent on some deeper dependencies and can't easily use this library in Scala.
Still, I'd be highly interested if anyone else has run into a similar problem.

Comment: @fozziethebeat Then try compiling it as a program and invoking it directly with "java". All you need to do is pass scala-library.jar in the classpath. Also, try using `-usejavacp` when running as a script.

Comment: @fozziethebeat I just thought of something... are you using relative paths to the jar files? If you are, don't. Use absolute paths.

Comment: @daniel-c-sobral Sadly both suggestions won't seem to work.  I can't compile the program with scalac, and -usejavacp didn't seem to change much.  But thanks for the suggestions.  For now, I think i'm just going to have to write this thing in java.

Answer (score 0):

Your script defines the object SaveTaggedSenseTask, but doesn't execute anything.

Just add

```
SaveTaggedSenseTask.main(args)
```

to the end of the script file. Or you can remove the object and def statements, like @daniel-c-sobral suggested.